# How to prevent “Tagging time” being set when tagging mp3 files from python (eyeD3)

Tags: python, mp3, eyed3

I want to use the script from
http://snipplr.com/view/4025/mp3-checksum-in-id3-tag/ to equip my mp3
collection with md5 checksums. The script can add a custom ID3 tag that
holds the checksum of the audio data and it has as well the option to
remove that checksum. Unfortunately adding and removing checksum does not
pass a round-trip test for several reasons. I want to change that. One
reason is that a “Tagging time” field is created when the script is run
but it is not removed when the checksum is removed, the time is even
updated. IIUC the `--no-tagging-time-frame` option will prevent this for the eyed3 tool on the command line, but I cannot find a python equivalent. How can I prevent the tagging time to be altered or set in python?

---

Some more details:

I added and subsequently removed a checksum on a copy of the original
file and compared both files. That's the differences of the binary data
for the best case:

Original:

```
0003 3060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0003 3070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0003 3080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0003 3090: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0003 30A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0003 30B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
```

Copy with checksum:

```
0003 3060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 58  58 58 00 00 00 21 00 00  ......TX XX...!..
0003 3070: 00 54 61 67 67 69 6E 67  20 74 69 6D 65 00 32 30  .Tagging time.20
0003 3080: 31 36 2D 30 31 2D 31 32  54 32 32 3A 33 31 3A 30  16-01-12 T22:31:0
0003 3090: 38 55 46 49 44 00 00 00  24 00 00 6D 64 35 00 64  8UFID... $..md5.d
0003 30A0: 34 35 64 30 62 32 34 36  38 62 31 64 38 31 31 35  45d0b246 8b1d8115
0003 30B0: 31 39 30 32 30 62 37 62  30 30 33 35 37 33 34 00  19020b7b 0035734.
```

Copy with checksum removed:

```
0003 3060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 58  58 58 00 00 00 21 00 00  ......TX XX...!..
0003 3070: 00 54 61 67 67 69 6E 67  20 74 69 6D 65 00 32 30  .Tagging time.20
0003 3080: 31 36 2D 30 31 2D 31 34  54 30 38 3A 33 34 3A 35  16-01-14 T08:34:5
0003 3090: 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  9....... ........
0003 30A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
0003 30B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........ ........
```

In other files more changes are introduced, I will come back to that
problem when the first one is solved.

Comment: What I wanted to add but only as comment: I tried to post the question to the project's mailing list first (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/eyed3-users). I even subscribed to the list by email (I have no google account) which worked, but my posts are still rejected.

Comment: What version of eyeD3 are you using?

Comment: I looked in 0.7.9 (the current version, I think) and couldn't find the code for the tagging time change.  Perhaps you could try that version?

Comment: Actually looks like the API is different and 0.7 won't work with your driver code ...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, I think, would be to move to the newer 0.7 series (or even use some other library - I like mutagen).  The 0.6.18 version is pretty old.  But doing either of these will break your script - the API has changed.

If you want to just make the minimal changes to the existing script, I suggest you just add

```
tag.do_tdtg = False
```

before each of the `tag.update` calls in the script.  I think that will turn off the time updating behaviour.